# Validation shows ï»¿<!DOCTYPE html> but can't find BOM character in file

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I wan't to pass validation for this site : 
http://www.mundo-satelital.com.ar/
but I can't seem to fix the strange character at the start of the file. The W3 validation service automatically detects my page as iso-8859-1 although I can see from the console on Firefox that the header being passed is `Content-Type  text/html; charset=utf-8` and my `<head>` contains

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

It seems what I'm looking for is a stray BOM character, apparently even one in the php includes can cause this, however I've been using `grep -rl $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' *.php` and variations of it to search for any .php, .html, .js or .css file that might be the culprit and after eliminating all those that turned up positive the problem is still present, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Question about your question. Shouldn't the doctype be on the first line of the file before anything else?

Comment: @GertKommer The doctype should be the very first line of the html output. That's the case here.

Comment: Is that the actual document you're validating? Can you narrow it down to a small, complete document that produces the problem, and post that? (I just tried throwing your example at the validator, and it told me that the HTTP Content-Type was, correctly, UTF-8...)

Comment: I don't know what happened but I went to bed, and the next morning validation no longer had this problem. I have no explanation (It wouldn't make sense to propose that W3 uses cached data for their analysis) but it's fixed now anyway. I gave the answer to @Sergiu Paraschiv because his answer was most detailed. Thanks you everyone though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header specified, the meta tag and the actual format your file is saved in are three totally different things. Make sure they are all the same. Also, right now you have a new line char (maybe chars if on windows) before your doctype. `<?php header ... ?>\n<!DOCTYPE...`

Answer (score 2):

Try to save them as UTF-8 non-BOM. (or without BOM, whatever it is called in your editor). Certainly this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't see the problem. When you cut and paste your code into validator, it goes without headers. If you set HTML5 doctype and utf-8 by yourself. Nothing will changed. you will still have 44 erors.